# how to do type validation of state in React class based component?

Tags: reactjs

I want to know how to do type validation of state in React class based component.
I found example of typechecking using proptypes but I need solution for states.
Thank you in advance

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/

Answer (score 0):

You can use Flow.https://flow.org/en/docs/.

Here is a great article on how to use it - https://medium.com/@krob/type-checking-state-in-react-components-with-flow-f1f1ec84f395

Comment: how to handle this.props.history.push('/home')
How can I define It in props?
I have tried like below but Its not working
type Prop = {
onLoginSuccess: function,
setContextDetails: function,
callErrorLogger: function,
history:string,
push:string
};

type State = {
username: string,
password: string,
loginsuccess: bool,
isLoading: bool
};

class Login extends React.Component<Prop, State> { }